how to solve UnboundLocalError
I'm trying to export data from database to display it on my django server. I'm still new to django, so I have been following some tutorials. I did exactly what's on the tutorial and I'm still getting an error that says "cannot access local variable 'Album' where it is not associated with a value".
I'm stuck, I don't even know where I'm getting it wrong.
views.py:
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Album


def index(request):
    all_albums = Album.objects.all()
    html = ''
    for Album in all_albums:
        path = '/music/' + str(album.id) + '/'
        html += '< a href="' + path + '">' + album.album_title + '</a></br>'
    return HttpResponse(html)


def detail(request, album_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Details for Album id:" + str(album_id) + "</h2>")


Inside index(), Album is a local variable (the loop variable of your for loop), NOT the object you imported from .models on the second line of the file.  Choose a different name for the loop variable, that doesn't shadow a global name.
